# Unable to Set Variable Before Table Loads

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I'm just learning Swift and trying to build an app that will fetch a podcast feed which I'll parse and use to populate a table. I'm 99% sure I'm running into an issue with the call being asynchronous. I can print the episode titles to the console so my parser works.  I just can't get the data to the table.  Here's what I'm attempting:

```
class EpisodeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {
    var podcastFocus :String = ""
    var episodes : [Episode] = []

    @IBAction func getEpisodesButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        getURLToParse()
    }

    // get URL and send to Parser
    func getURLToParse() {
        if let url = URL(string: podcastFocus) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                } else {
                    if data != nil{
                        let parser = Parser()
                        self.episodes = parser.getPodcastMetadata(data: data!)
                        print(self.episodes)
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where's your attempt to reload the table view once the data is loaded?

Comment: @rmaddy's comment is the answer.

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy .  I actually tried that prior to posting (should have mentioned that) but I 'm not sure I am putting it in the right place.  After seeing your response I added the IBOutlet for the tableview and place 'self.epTableView.reloadData()' in the getURLToParse function but to no avail.

Comment: Ah.  Got it!  I had to dispatch it to the main queue first.  Thank you @rmaddy